# Crash of DIN software with Driver OPC-UA

Tags: milo

In my DIN application, where i use "Milo OPC-UA Driver", I have a repeating error log:

```
20:55:18.254 [milo-shared-thread-pool-8] WARN org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.SessionFsm - [2] Keep Alive failureCount=2 exceeds failuresAllowed=1
20:55:23.254 [milo-shared-thread-pool-4] WARN org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.SessionFsm - [2] Keep Alive failureCount=3 exceeds failuresAllowed=1
20:55:27.192 [milo-netty-event-loop-1] ERROR org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.transport.uasc.UascClientMessageHandler - [remote=/192.168.20.103:4840] Exception caught: Connection in progress forcefully terminated by remote host
```

After these messages my application crashes and to restart it I have to restart the server service on which it runs.

Most likely it is due to a blocking of the threads that make the request to the OPC-UA device, which remain open for some reason, probably repeated attempts to reconnect to the device.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are telling you the server on the other end of the connection stopped responding and eventually the socket was closed.

Beyond that, you haven’t provided anywhere near enough information to help you.

Comment: Do you know a solution for the "BadToManyOperations" error? When this error appears the PLC no longer responds and no longer accepts incoming connections.

Comment: It means some request sent but he client requested to e.g. read, write, create too many things, and you need to split it into batches.

Comment: This happens when I send too many read requests to the PLC sequentially (one after the other) in a short time. Do you know a way to set a timeout in receiving the response and a way to delete any requests already sent to the PLC? Because this error leads me to the PLC blocking.